# Accessing pointer to a vector in a struct

Tags: c++, struct

How can I access the value of a pointer to a vector in a struct? I've got the following code:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct item {
    int value;
    vector<bool> pb;
    vector<bool> *path = &pb;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<item> dp(10);
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        dp[n].pb = vector<bool>(10);

    if (dp[1].path[2] == true)
        cout << "true";
    else cout << "false";
}
```

Which results in the following compilation error:

```
Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector<bool,std::allocator<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

How can I access the value stored at dp[1].path[2]?

Comment: The same way you access a value from a pointer to a vector that is not in a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

path is a pointer to a vector. You have to do the following to access the value in the vector that it points to

```
if ((*(dp[1].path))[2] == true)
```

or

```
if (dp[1].path->operator[](2) == true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can use `at` [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) which is also

> checks whether n is within the bounds of valid elements in the vector

code example

```
if (dp[1].path->at(2) == true)
```